# Not able to upload image to server with retrofit

Tags: java, file-upload, retrofit, retrofit2

I am currently working on a personal project in which I want to upload a profile pic to my server. I can easily put an image to a server with postman by sending it in form-data but when I do the same with retrofit it does not work, and sometimes it creates a 1kb file which shows an error when opening.

### What currently I am doing is,

```java
 Uri uri = data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Profile", "bcs.jpeg", reqFile);
                authViewModel.setNewProfilePic(layout,email,body);
```

### and code for setNewProfilePic is,

```java
public void setNewProfilePic(RelativeLayout relativeLayout, String email,MultipartBody.Part part) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        api = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.URL_API).client(client).build().create(SpendistryAPI.class);
        retrofit2.Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> req = api.setNewProfilePic(email,part);
        req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                // Do Something
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(application, "notWorking: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(application, response.body().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(application, "catch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

if i provie file to RequestBody.create like,

```java
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file);
```

code of setting new profile pic does not get executed and if I pass only URI.getPath() in .create() method id creates image file on the server with 1kb which can not be opened.

please help me with this situation, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is that you might not have given the read external storage permission, ***uri.getPath()*** will not work, you have to find a real path from uri for that you can use this code

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Now, pass this string to file otherwise code is perfect!

```
FILE file = new file(getRealPathFromURI(uri));
```